# Можно ли использрвать код на питоне, но андроид приложение написать на джава

Tags: java, android, python, android-studio

Есть код программы на питоне (писал не я), я хочу на джаве создать андроид приложение, можно ли как-то код на питоне реализовать в приложении (я использую андроид студио, может, эта информация пригодится)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python можно использовать вместе с Java, я встречал примеры, но к сожалению ссылки на источник нет.

Поискав в google, я нашел ответ на ваш вопрос [*ссылка на источник*](https://towardsdatascience.com/tools-to-run-python-on-android-9060663972b4?gi=c238a3083cc8) автор статьи привел интересные проекты, которые помогут вам в разработки приложения для Android на Python, и там же вы найдете ссылку на плагин [**Chaquopy**](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/) для Android Studio.

> Chaquopy enables you to freely intermix Java and Python in your app, using whichever language is best for your needs:

Если мой ответ помог вам, тогда примите ответ.